# which event is raised if the request URL only for rewrite rule but not for my controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net

[Here is the full list of events which raised by `HttpApplication`.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx)

Which event is raised after `ASP.NET` saw that the request URL is not valid for any of my controllers but valid for at list one `rewrite` rule - and happens **before** `ASP.NET` actually rewriting the request?

```
ASP.NETsee new request
V
...
V
ASP.NET check URL if it's good for any of my controllers
V
URL isn't valid for any of my controllers
V
...
V
<<<<--------- This one I want
V
...
V
ASP.NET check URL if it's good for any of my rewrite rules
V
...
V
ASP.NET forward the request to one of my rewrite rules
V
...
```

Why? To check authorization only for requests which needs to be `rewrite` & add additional headers before `ASP.NET` rewriting the request.

Comment: If you mean `rewrite` rules in `web.config` then they run *before* any `HttpApplication` events.

Comment: Then why `ASP.NET` rewrite my request only after `HttpApplication.PostAcquireRequestState` event is triggered?